# 'NS_ITEMINFO::AddTextNoSplit' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'BYTE' to 'CString'

Tags: c++, string

I get a compilation error on the line:

```
GLPADATA &sDamage = sItemCustom.getdamage();
nExtraValue = sItemCustom.GETGRADE_DAMAGE();
uGRADE = sItemCustom.GETGRADE(EMGRINDING_DAMAGE);
AddInfoItemAddonRange ( sDamage.dwLow, sDamage.dwHigh, nExtraValue, uGRADE,ID2GAMEWORD("ITEM_ADVANCED_INFO", 0) );
AddTextNoSplit (uGRADE, NS_UITEXTCOLOR::GOLD);
```

I don't know how to resolve this error, and what I'm trying to do is to have the uGRADE a different color from the default color of ID2GAMEWORD. I'm currently still learning

Comment: What is the type of `uGRADE`? How is `AddTextNoSplit` declared?

Comment: uGRADE is for BYTES/NUMBERS and AddTextNoSplit is for text only if I'm not mistaken, well this is a free source which I tried so I can start learning. lmao